# Add app in Opportunities page

Tags: opportunity, app

You are building an app for Salesforce and you want to add the app container in Opportunities page, like Evernote app does (see image below).

[image]

How you can do that?

Best Regards,

Fabrício Ferrari de Campos

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, Fabricio. What have you tried so far? Have you looked into Canvas? You'll get better responses if you provide us better details on what you have tried and why those methods did not work.

Answer (score 3):

What they are doing is leveraging a feature of the [Layout editor in Salesforce](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_layoutcustomize_pd.htm&language=en_US). To enable you to embed a Visualforce page into a section. The steps are this....

1. Create a [Visualforce page using the Standard controller](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_std_associate.htm) for the object.
2. Click in the Layout palette at the top of the editor, the **Visualforce Pages** section.
3. Drag and drop a new **Section** into the part of the layout you require.
4. Drag and drop your **Visualforce page** into the new section.

**NOTE:** Visualforce pages can also contain on them a technology known as [Canvas](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/platform_connect/), which allows your page and thus the layout it is placed on, to punch out to an externally hosted web page.

Here is an example Visualforce page, as shown in the screenshots below...

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity">
    <span>Put here what ever HTML you want!</span>
    <span>You can also reference fields from the Opportunity, e.g. {!Opportunity.Name</span>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

The resulting page looks like this...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have several options to achieve this.

1) Add a Visualforce Page with an `iFrame` linked to the site you want

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity">
    <iframe src="http://www.yoursite.com" />
</apex:page>
```

2) Use Salesforce canvas app ([`apex:canvasApp`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_canvasApp.htm), [Force.com Canvas](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_Canvas))